# how to configure nginx as a forward proxy that correctly handles POST requests?-- GETs work, but POSTs result in 404s

Tags: post, nginx, proxy

I'm new to nginx, and tried to follow this tutorial  -- https://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server --
to set up a forward proxy, and it sort of works, but only for GET requests, not POSTs.   If you have docker 
I can provide a reproducible test case via the SETUP_NGINX script below.   (I've tested the script on Linux, 
but the volume mount may not work on the Mac unless you locate the nginx.conf under /Users)

The script uses the identical nginx.conf as that in the article I referenced above.
The problem with POSTs only occurs when I try to POST to services that are running 
on localhost.  POSTs to remote services work fine.   But I really want to setup nginx so it 
can proxy to services running locally (for testing purposes.)

To reproduce the issue, you can setup mongodb to run locally in Docker as shown below.
The only reason I chose mongodb is that it is quick to setup to run locally, and it
accepts POST requests out of the box.

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -p 28017:28017 --name some-mongo   -e AUTH=no -d mongo  --rest --httpinterface
# verify you can send a POST
curl   -v -d '{ "A1" : 201 }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:28017/local/example1
# the above command will return {"OK": true }  when NOT run via proxy.
```

Next, you can setup a proxy just like I did by copy pasting the script in SETUP_NGINX.
After setting up the proxy on 9999, you can proxy GETs just fine. For example, this command:

```
curl --proxy localhost:9999   http://httpbin.org/get
```

gives almost same result as when we don't specify --proxy localhost:9999  (it does include an extra header that shows
its being proxied).

You can also proxy POST request to httpbin.org, like this:

```
curl  --proxy localhost:9999   --data "param1=value1" http://httpbin.org/post
```

But now, let's say i wanted to proxy a POST request to my locally running mongodb.
I execute a curl command almost identical to the first curl command (above):

```
curl  --proxy localhost:9999   -v -d '{ "A1" : 201 }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:28017/local/example2
```

But this time I will get a 404 not found.   If you remove the --proxy switch
it will work fine.  Any assistance greatly appreciated !

**SETUP_NGINX**

```
cat  >nginx.conf <<'END'
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       9999;
        location / {
            resolver 8.8.8.8;
            proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
END

docker run -d  --name nginxproxy -p 9999:9999 -p 80:80    -v `pwd`/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf  nginx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from my colleague Vignesh, we came up with an answer as to what's going on here.   When issuing the request to mongo, we use the URL "http://localhost:28017/local/example1"  as the REST endpoint.  This URL gets passed to the proxy server (nginx) which is running in it's own docker container.. From the perspective of the proxy server there is no mongodb server running within the docker container, so it gives up, and sends back 404.

The problem can be avoided as follows:

- keep the nginx config exactly as it is.
- set $IP to the ip address of the machine where you are launching docker.

Then, when you POST to mongo, via the proxy, do so like this:
  curl  --proxy localhost:9999   -v -d '{ "A1" : 201 }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://$IP:28017/local/example2

Note that we have swapped $IP for localhost in the URL above.

Using the explicit IP, rather than localhost  resolves the issue.